# Window Phone Click on button with image show blue square

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Here is the button code:

```
<Button x:Name="openSearchButton" Content="" BorderThickness="0" Click="openSearchButton_Click" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="70" Padding="0" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/search.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

When I click on the button, blue square shows instead the image.

Before:

[image: Before clicking]

After:

[image: After clicking]

Note: I run this application via visual studio and my device which connected to the computer via USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visual effect on button click is due to style sheet applied to button by-default. If you want change this behavior or give custom effect on various events of control just go through following steps:

1: open page in blend(you can do in VS itself but I prefer Blend)

2: click on button which you want change behavior got to properties windows

3: Or right click on it and select edit template-> edit copy

4: name a template and keep it in standardstylesheet.xml file to access it on all pages where you  want same behavior

5: Now go for storyboard section of each event and style on event applied, and change accordingly.
From above point you will come to know how deal with such situation. Please mark it as solution as I know it give answer to your question.

Comment: Just a reference - [Here is a defalut style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069(v=vs.95).aspx) -

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But could you please provide next steps? A lot of code appeared after these actions and it will be great to understand how to change <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"> (I believe this is a piece of code to work with) to apply an image to pressed state. And maybe you have an advice how to refactor all these XAML code to make it more compact, leave only parts that suits our needs and get rid of everything else. Thanks in advance.